# How to fill an entry box created by a loop in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Basically I created many Entry boxes and I want to fill it when clicked a specific button but when I did this it fills only the last one. I know I can just create the boxes one by one but is there any way to do it like that.

```
def Roll_Dice(Dice):
    if Dice=="d6":
        Rolls=[]
        for i in range(0,4):
            Rolls.append(random.randint(1,6))
        return Rolls
    elif Dice=="d20":
        return random.randint(1,20)
def check(name):
    if name=="Str":
        StrDice.append(Roll_Dice("d6"))
        StrRoll.config(state="disabled")
        Fill(name,StrDice)
def Fill(stat,list):
    if stat=="Str":
        for i in range(0,4):
            strength.insert(i,list[i])
STR=LabelFrame(root,text="Str")
STR.place(x=10,y=10)
j=0
for i in range(0,4):
    j+=1
    strength=Entry(STR)
    strength.grid(row=j,column=0,pady=5)
```

```
STATS=Frame(root)
STATS.place(x=10,y=150)
StrRoll=Button(STATS,text="Roll for your Str stats",command=lambda:check("Str"))
StrRoll.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=1,padx=2)
```

Here is all my code:

```
from tkinter import*
import functions
import random
root=Tk()
StrDice=[]
DexDice=[]
IntDice=[]
ConsDice=[]
WisDice=[]
CharDice=[]
def Roll_Dice(Dice):
    if Dice=="d6":
        Rolls=[]
        for i in range(0,4):
            Rolls.append(random.randint(1,6))
        return Rolls
    elif Dice=="d20":
        return random.randint(1,20)
def check(name):
    if name=="Str":
        StrDice.append(Roll_Dice("d6"))
        StrRoll.config(state="disabled")
        Fill(name,StrDice)
    elif name=="Dex":
        DexDice.append(Roll_Dice("d6"))
        DexRoll.config(state="disabled")
    elif name=="Int":
        IntDice.append(Roll_Dice("d6"))
        IntRoll.config(state="disabled")
    elif name=="Cons":
        ConsDice.append(Roll_Dice("d6"))
        ConsRoll.config(state="disabled")
    elif name=="Wis":
        WisDice.append(Roll_Dice("d6"))
        WisRoll.config(state="disabled")
    else:
        CharDice.append(Roll_Dice("d6"))
        CharRoll.config(state="disabled")
def Fill(stat,list):
    if stat=="Str":
        for i in range(0,4):
            strength.insert(i,list[i])
    pass
Stats=["Str","Dex","Int","Cons","Wis","Char"]
STR=LabelFrame(root,text="Str")
STR.place(x=10,y=10)
j=0
for i in range(0,4):
    j+=1
    strength=Entry(STR)
    strength.grid(row=j,column=0,pady=5)
DEX=LabelFrame(root,text="Dex")
DEX.place(x=140,y=10)
j=0
for i in range(0,4):
    j+=1
    Dexterity=Entry(DEX)
    Dexterity.grid(row=j,column=0,pady=5)
INT=LabelFrame(root,text="Int")
INT.place(x=270,y=10)
j=0
for i in range(0,4):
    j+=1
    Intelligence=Entry(INT)
    Intelligence.grid(row=j,column=0,pady=5)
CONS=LabelFrame(root,text="Cons")
CONS.place(x=400,y=10)
j=0
for i in range(0,4):
    j+=1
    Constitution=Entry(CONS)
    Constitution.grid(row=j,column=0,pady=5)
WIS=LabelFrame(root,text="Wis")
WIS.place(x=530,y=10)
j=0
for i in range(0,4):
    j+=1
    Wisdom=Entry(WIS)
    Wisdom.grid(row=j,column=0,pady=5)
CHAR=LabelFrame(root,text="Char")
CHAR.place(x=660,y=10)
j=0
for i in range(0,4):
    j+=1
    Charisma=Entry(CHAR)
    Charisma.grid(row=j,column=0,pady=5)
STATS=Frame(root)
STATS.place(x=10,y=150)
StrRoll=Button(STATS,text="Roll for your Str stats",command=lambda:check("Str"))
StrRoll.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=1,padx=2)
DexRoll=Button(STATS,text="Roll for your Dex stats",command=lambda:check("Dex"))
DexRoll.grid(row=0,column=1,columnspan=1,padx=2)
IntRoll=Button(STATS,text="Roll for your Int stats",command=lambda:check("Int"))
IntRoll.grid(row=0,column=2,columnspan=1,padx=2)
ConsRoll=Button(STATS,text="Roll for your Cons stats",command=lambda:check("Cons"))
ConsRoll.grid(row=0,column=3,columnspan=1,padx=2)
WisRoll=Button(STATS,text="Roll for your Wis stats",command=lambda:check("Wis"))
WisRoll.grid(row=0,column=4,columnspan=1,padx=2)
CharRoll=Button(STATS,text="Roll for your Char stats",command=lambda:check("Char"))
CharRoll.grid(row=0,column=5,columnspan=1,padx=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your "all the code" part is not working. Can you make sure, that this is the code you are able to execute. Even after I fixed some of it, you'll still have index errors. Also, don't use list as variable name, it is a reserved keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot you could do to simplify what you're trying to achieve, but I'll keep it simple and just answer your question.

In the loop where you create the widgets, you are reassigning the variable on each iteration. By the time the loop is finished, your variable, 'strength' in the first example, is only referencing the last entry widget created.

A simple solution could be to place the widgets in a list:

```
strength = []
for i in range(4):
    strength.append(Entry(STR))
    strength[i].grid(row=i, column=0, pady=5
```

Then later when inserting:

```
strength[i].insert(0, value)
```

**EDIT:** Here's a quick and dirty example of simplifying/shortening your code. The totals assume you're doing 4d6, drop the lowest.

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


STAT_BLOCKS = ['STR', 'DEX', 'CON', 'WIS', 'INT', 'CHA']

fields = {}
buttons = {}
labels = {}

def roll_dice(num_sides, num_dice=1):
    return [random.randint(1, num_sides) for i in range(num_dice)]

def fill(stat, rolled_values):
    for idx, value in enumerate(rolled_values):
        fields[stat][idx].insert(0, value)
    buttons[stat].config(state='disabled')
    labels[stat].config(text=f'Total: {sum(sorted(rolled_values)[1:])}')

def reset():
    for stat in STAT_BLOCKS:
        for field in fields[stat]:
            field.delete(0, 'end')
        buttons[stat].config(state='normal')
        labels[stat].config(text='')


root = tk.Tk()

for stat in STAT_BLOCKS:
    frame = ttk.Labelframe(root, text=stat)
    frame.pack(side='left', padx=10)

    buttons[stat] = ttk.Button(
        frame,
        text='ROLL',
        command=lambda s=stat: fill(s, roll_dice(6, 4))
    )
    buttons[stat].pack(pady=5)

    fields[stat] = [ttk.Entry(frame, width=3, justify='right')
                    for i in range(4)]
    for field in fields[stat]:
        field.pack(pady=(0, 5))

    labels[stat] = ttk.Label(frame)
    labels[stat].pack(pady=(0, 5))

reset_button = ttk.Button(text='Reset', command=reset).pack(side='right', padx=(0, 10))

root.mainloop()
```